# ios7 how can I get UITableViewCell's UISwitch value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I'm using UISwitch on UITableViewCell. When I the push save button, I want to get UISwitch value. How can I get it? My code listed below:

```
- (void)save:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *commentCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomInfoCell" forIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    UISwitch* commentSwitch = (UISwitch*)[commentCell viewWithTag:2];

    NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:commentSwitch.on]);
}
```

Comment: so what? `commentSwitch.on` is that what you want already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)save:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *commentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    UISwitch* commentSwitch = (UISwitch*)[commentCell viewWithTag:2];

    NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:commentSwitch.on]);
}
```